# Find the Nearest Control Dependent statement at LLVM IR level

Tags: llvm

everyone. Recently I've digging on find the nearest control dependent statement of an instruction at LLVM IR level. An example looks like below:

```
char buffer[10];
if(i > 5 && i < 10) {
  if(i == 6) {
    buffer[0] = 'a';
  } else if(...) {
    ...
  }

  // some other irrelevant code
  ...

  buffer[1] = 's'; // <---- target
}
```

Say, if we want to determine target statement's nearest control dependent condition, namely:

```
i > 5 && i < 10
```

Is there a way to get this condtion? I have already tried to traverse DominatorTree from target's corresponding basic block to root node, but since

```
i == 6
```

dominates target instruction too, it's not a good idea to determine the **real** nearest control dependent condition by DominatorTree.

Any suggestions will be helpful, thanks!

Comment: I think that the definition you're looking for is the "Control Dependence" definition for a CFG, such as the one described in these slides: https://www.cs.utexas.edu/~pingali/CS380C/2016-fall/lectures/Dominators.pdf (page 6).  Given a CFG G, a node w is control-dependent on an edge (u->v) if
1) w postdominates v
2) if w is not u, w does not postdominate u

Comment: To add on my previous comment, remember that there may be instructions that may not return / may throw. Then, you may also have a control dependency with the instructions that may-not-return/may-throw that and that can reach your statemen (through any path).

Comment: @jmmartinez Thanks for your suggestion. I suppose post domniator tree may work and I am currently trying on it.

Answer (score 0):

Following the discussion in your question, I think the snippet you're looking for is the following:

```cpp
// see if I depends from Term through to a control-dependency
bool HasControlDep(PostDominatorTree &PDT, Instruction *Term, Instruction *I) {
  assert(Term->isTerminator());

  BasicBlock *U = Term->getParent();
  BasicBlock *W = I->getParent();

  for (BasicBlock *V : successors(U)) {
    if (!PDT.dominates(W, V))
      continue;
    if(W != U && !PDT.dominates(W, U))
      return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```